# AngularJS push multiple rows from module

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a form where the user choose a supplier from a select box, then a button to choose an item.
When he click the button, a module open and he can search for items. Result came into a table in the module, next to each row there is a + symbol, when he clicks the +, the row come outside the module, and place itself in the table in the main form.

```
 <table>
 <tr ng-repeat="row in searchitems">
 <td>...</td>
 <td>...</td>
 <td> <a data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="additemfound(row)"></a> </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

javascript code:

```
$scope.additemfound = function(row){
$scope.rowrequest.push(row)};
```

here i get the row that i chose from the module to the main form and the module close.
I need to push from the module multi row, not only one by one, any solution ?

Comment: Show us your jsfiddle to understand the exact problem.

Comment: it's impossible to do that, i don't have access online in my  job on the localhost

Comment: Add some `console.log` into your `$scope.additemfound` function and see if it is invoked and with what (stringifying the `row` object).

Comment: i don't have problem with the function, but  i want to push more than 1 row not only 1

Comment: How do you want the user to select more rows? Click on the + symbol on multiple rows?

Comment: sorry for late reply, timezone difference, I added in every row a check box, and a button at the end of the module, the user should check multi items and click the button to push all the checked rows to the main table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the table :

```
<tr ng-repeat =" row in rowssearchitems"" ng-class="{'selected':
row.selected}" ng-click="addItemFound(row)">
```

in js

```
$scope.addItemFound = function(row) {
row.selected ? row.selected = false : row.selected = true;
```

in html again:

```
<button ng-click="getallrows();">Get all rows </button>
```

js:

```
 $scope.getallrows = function(){
 var selectedrows = $filter("filter")($scope.rowssearchitems, {
 selected : true}, true);
 for (var i=0;i<selectedrows.length;i++){
 var selectedrowsdata = selectedrows[i];
 $scope.rowsrequests.push(selectedrows[i])}
```

What I did :
I gave a class selected to every row where the user click on the row and the class become selected true then a loop on all rows selected true and push those rows to the main table